# Firebase notification not receivig even though I got InstanceID token from android in log Xamarim

Tags: xamarin.android, android-emulator, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Xamarin, I want to use firebase cloud messaging services, I am following the instruction given here(Remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin]).
When I ran the app and got the InstanceID token from log window, but when I used it in firebase console to send notification I am not getting the notification in my android app running in emulator. Please help me know, what can be the reason for the same to not working. Will appreciate your support.

Comment: Have you [declare the receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin#declare-the-receiver-in-the-android-manifest) in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes, This is my AndroidManifest.xml file contain:
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" 
              android:exported="false" />

Comment: <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" 
              android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" 
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>